# How to save a file from Linux on to your desktop?

Tags: putty, file-transfer

I have began using Putty.exe on a university computer that is also connected to the university server. I have a pdb file saved in my Linux directory. Is it possible to save this pdb file onto the desktop of the current computer I am using so I can e-mail it to myself?

I would like to learn how to save Linux files onto my desktop (when using the university server). I have researched on my own and have found out that when you are using your own computer or personal laptop at home, I could potentially save a file (using command cp to copy it actually) to my desktop using a direct path however, I am having trouble completing this on a university server.

Answer (score 2):

Using SCP with `pscp` is a good option, as given by sebasth. SFTP with `psftp` is another option. You probably cannot install software on the university workstation, but you can probably [download](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) and execute Putty's `psftp`, which is "command-line secure file copy."

When you first start this program, it might look as follows.

```
psftp: no hostname specified; use "open host.name" to connect
psftp>
```

Do this using the same credentials that you use for SSH. For example,

```
psftp> open server.university.edu
```

(Or, use its IP address if you don't have a hostname.)

Type `help` to view available commands. Of note, pay attention to `lcd`. The meaning is "local change directory." This changes the working directory of the program. When you download a file, the file will be downloaded into the working directory. One might use `lpwd` to print the local working directory. Also note that local commands can be executed with `!`. To get a local directory listing, type `!dir`. As an exercise, try these to get a feel for what is happening.

```
lcd \
!dir
lcd Users
!dir
lcd YourUserName
!dir
lcd Desktop
lpwd
```

Now, get a directory listing on the remote side.

```
ls
```

Use `get` to download a single file. Use `mget` to download multiple files at once, for example, `mget a*` to download all files beginning with the lower-case letter, a. (The uploads use `put` and `mput`.)

To end the SFTP session, type `bye`.

On a personal computer where you can install software, try any SFTP client. FileZilla. WinSCP. WinSSHFS. Or search for one you like best.

Comment: Great! This is my next step. Well, first step actually is to learn what SFTP is and then proceed from there. Thank you.

Comment: @Christopher SFTP is not FTP over SSH. It's often confused because they have superficial similarity from the user level but SFTP is a totally different protocol than FTP.

Comment: Note that SFTP needs to be enabled by the server admin for it to work. This is an advantage that SCP has over SFTP, as SCP is always available whenever you have shell access.

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY should come with scp client [`pscp`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp). You can use it from command line:

```
pscp user@host:source target
```

Where *user* and *host* refer to the server you are connecting to. *Source* is the path to the file on server, and *target* is path to where you want to save the file on your client.

If you are using Linux client, your system possibly already has `scp` installed. `scp` can be used with same syntax.

Comment: Ok, I understand how to find paths to other parts within your directories in Linux, but without giving away the answer (or command), is it possible to find the path to the desktop of the current computer you are using, in other words, can you access folders outside of linux? (For example, "My Documents" in Windows?)

Comment: You could open command line (cmd), navigate to directory you want to save the file and then execute `\Path\To\pscp.exe user@host:source .`; For finding user directory path on Windows, see [this related question on SO about finding user directory on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9228950/8270535).

Comment: No you can't read out from remote computer to local (when using ssh (putty)). You need to run a putty command on the local machine, to go grab the file. You could do a ssh back from the remote to the local, but you seem to be using Microsoft's Windows (so you can't).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor
I was told about some program called Filezilla that can do this. Another classmate did the same! She used Filezilla to save a file she has saved in her Linux directory and then you could see the file on her desktop. (The desktop was on a university's computer)

Comment: If you have a MS-Windows file share, then you can mount it in Gnu/Linux (If it is visible from that machine). It may be better to ask the local IT-support team, at the university.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that the answer that most directly answers you question is scp (pscp if using putty).

However another solution, is to install a revision control system, you should do this anyway, as they are very very useful. I recommend mercurial (hg) (others will recommend git, but it is much harder to learn).

- Install tourtoisehg on both MS-windows, and Gnu/Linux,

  - on Debian/Ubuntu etc type `sudo apt install tortoisehg-nautilus` (and wait 2 minutes).
  - on MS-Windows goto https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/ download install (and wait ½ hour).
- get an account at [bit-bucket](https://bitbucket.org), and
- learn how it works: There are many tutorials, I don't know which is best. If you can't find them, then ask, and I will direct you to some.

You can save the entire history of your project, so can undo changes from weeks ago (if you need to). **You can also synchronise multiple computers via bitbucket.**

Comment: I wish I could ask you to explain this like I'm 5. I can do this. Thank you.

Comment: @IsabelEstrellaSanchez Sorry but you last comment is confusing me. (it reads, I wish I could ask for help (yes you can do this), I already know how to do this).  Are you asking for help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MS-Windows file share (probably in a university, as you need this for MS-Windows to have you files on every machine in the university), then you can mount it in Gnu/Linux (If it is visible from that machine: probably is if also in the university). It may be better to ask the local IT-support team, at the university, to find out how.